# Some tricky configurations in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to set up some security configurations over my server, but I've checked file `postgresql.conf` and I just managed to change the IP it listens to.

What I am looking to do is the following:

- Just allow ips to connect in range of 80.120.x.x
- From those ips, everyone should be prompted for password, except the ones in 80.120.1.x which are admins, and should't prompt for password.

Is this possible with postgre? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into the `pg_hba.conf` file.  You will find it in the same directory where you found `postgresql.conf`.